# iOS UITableView header with sticky menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I want to create a `UITableView` with an collapsable view on top and a sticky menu. To show what i exactly mean i made 3 images:

[image: State full expanded]

[image: State while scrolling down]

[image: State header collapsed]

I thought i will make a `UITableViewController` and place a view above the table but i dont know how to implement the sticky menu.

Whats the best way to accomplish that?

Comment: is your header contains list of items? means is it scrollable ? or just display list of items open.

Comment: it is not scrollable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `UITableViewController`, you won't be able to add anything besides the table view.

You should use a standard `UIViewController`, with a top view housing the sticky menu, and a `UITableView` below it.

You can open/close the menu by using autolayout: your sticky menu has a "fixed height" constraint, and the table view has no "top" constraint, but a "vertical spacing" constraint between the sticky menu and itself.

Just animate the constant for the "height" constraint of the menu to have a collapse/expand animation.

Answer (score -1):

You should add a table Header for Sticky menu.